# Counter question

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.  I have a problem related to my code.  My problem is I have my two PCs.  They have counter software, with timer code on the first PC. The main problem is, when the counter software is stopped on first PC, the counter 
on the other computer should stop as well (without sql connection)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not tried something so far.

Comment: you are more likely to get an answer if you state what you have tried and what did not work or what the problems were

Comment: There are many [communication protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols) and many communication frameworks. It's all depend on your needs (reliability, performance, etc.) and your network (LAN, internet, etc.). I suggest you to be more specific about your exact needs.

Comment: @HuBeZa LAN connection type is required.IP communication protocol is required.

Comment: This sounds waaaay too general and much too close to a "please do my job/homework for me".  As Sam Holder said, post what you have so far and why it doesn't work, and people can help you fix it.

Comment: @Noah I just tried with SQL Connection so far.But ,I just wanna   with IP protocol communication. I Don't said to do homework/job for me.Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: with no more info, i will suggest you check [WCF samples](http://www.google.com/search?q=WCF+samples) over the web. It's a .NET abstraction for many types of service communication, and much more

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a service on the second box that will accept a "stop" request from the first box. You could use...

- A WCF service (TCP/IP, IIS Hosted etc)
- A web service (IIS Hosted)

Then you just call the service from the first box,

```
CounterService.StopCounter();
```

Tutorial on writing a WCF service:

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Writing_the_WCF_Hello_World_App.aspx